# Return Null to database user creation

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms

I was working on my project and i found a bug in my **`AbstractUser`** Model. I have certain fields set to **`null=True`** and i realized that whenever i create a user, those field do not return **`null`** to database.

Here is my **`AbstractUser`** Model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=9, default="", unique=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default="avatar.png",
        upload_to="images",
        validators=[validate_pic_extension],
    )
    password2 = models.CharField(
        default=None,
        max_length=128,
        verbose_name="Confirm Password",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    email = models.EmailField(default=None, max_length=255, unique=True)
    designation = models.CharField(
        default="Student", choices=DESIGNATION, max_length=255, null=True, blank=True
    )
    staff_id = models.CharField(
        default=None,
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="Staff Id",
    )
    matric_no = models.CharField(
        default=None,
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="Matric Number",
    )
    lib_user = models.CharField(
        default=None,
        max_length=255,
        choices=LIBUSER,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="Library User",
    )
    library_id = models.CharField(
        default=None,
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="Library Card Id",
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

views.py

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Signup(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST.get("username")
            first_name = request.POST.get("first_name")
            last_name = request.POST.get("last_name")
            email = request.POST.get("email")
            password = request.POST.get("password")
            password2 = request.POST.get("password2")
            staff_id = request.POST.get("staff_id")
            matric_no = request.POST.get("matric_no")
            library_id = request.POST.get("library_id")
            designation = request.POST.get("designation")
            lib_user = request.POST.get("lib_user")
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=username.lower(),
                first_name=first_name.lower(),
                last_name=last_name.lower(),
                password=password,
                email=email,
                staff_id=staff_id,
                matric_no=matric_no,
                library_id=library_id,
                designation=designation,
                lib_user=lib_user,
            )
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "Account Created successfully for " + username)
            return redirect(signin)
    else:
        form = Signup()
    return render(request, "accounts/register.html", {"form": form})
```

forms.py validation

```
def clean(self):
        super(Signup, self).clean()
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        staff_id = self.cleaned_data.get("staff_id")
        matric_no = self.cleaned_data.get("matric_no")
        library_id = self.cleaned_data.get("library_id")

        if not staff_id:
            self.cleaned_data["staff_id"] = None
```

So basically, i select if i user is a staff or student. If user is student, **staff_id** field is meant to return **`null`** to database. So how do i go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check after changes `null=True, blank=True` you applied `makemigrations` and `migrate` command applied or not, if applied then try this code

------ Code - 1 ---------

```
def signup(request):
    form = Signup()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Signup(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            fm=form.save()
            login(request, fm.user)
            messages.success(request, "Account Created successfully for " + form.claned_data['username'])
            return redirect(signin)
    return render(request, "accounts/register.html", {"form": form})
```

--------- Code - 2 ------------

```
def signup(request):
    form = Signup()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Signup(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            first_name = form.cleaned_data["first_name"]
            last_name = form.cleaned_data["last_name"]
            email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            password2 = form.cleaned_data["password2"]
            staff_id = form.cleaned_data["staff_id"]
            matric_no = form.cleaned_data["matric_no"]
            library_id = form.cleaned_data["library_id"]
            designation = form.cleaned_data["designation"]
            lib_user = form.cleaned_data["lib_user"]
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=username.lower(),
                first_name=first_name.lower(),
                last_name=last_name.lower(),
                password=password,
                email=email,
                staff_id=staff_id,
                matric_no=matric_no,
                library_id=library_id,
                designation=designation,
                lib_user=lib_user,
            )
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "Account Created successfully for " + username)
            return redirect(signin)
    return render(request, "accounts/register.html", {"form": form})
```